# How to find out does url contain img or other file? And how to exclude those files and download just images?

Tags: python, image, http

I have a data set that contains URLs of the images but some URLs are zipped files of the images. How can I download just from those URLs that contained just images?

Comment: Post your code so that we can help you better.

Comment: Hello @Anna Tum, Could you please update more information about your issue? and feedback my answer. If any issue from my answer, please feedback to me soon.

Answer (score 0):

First, download all the data from those URLs and put them in a directory. This folder will contain image files and compressed image files (as you say).
Use the `os` library to access the .zip or .rar files to extract all the images, now you will have a folder full of images.

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

extension = [".zip"]
path = "directory contain all files"
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()       
        if ext in extension:
            with ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as zip: 
                # printing all the contents of the zip file 
                zip.printdir()            
                # extracting all the files 
                print('Extracting all the files now...') 
                zip.extractall() 
                print('Done!')
```

Here it is anyway and hopefully you or someone else can come up with a better method.